# Can there be two complex roots for the square root of a negative number?

Tags: complex-numbers

Can the Square root of $(-9)$ have two answers namely $+3i$ or $-3i$?

Squaring both $3i$ and $-3i$ does give $-9$.

Why does my text book say only $3i$?

Comment: Both $3i$ and $-3i$ are valid solutions, you're right. The reason they might ignore the negative solution is possibly that they're only considering what's called the "principal" solution ($3i$) and they either think it's implied or irrelevant that $-3i$ is also a solution. But nevertheless, you're right that there are two solutions.

Comment: How does your textbook define the square root? The equation $x^2 = -9$ has the two solutions you gave.

Comment: @gammatester -9 nested in a Square Root(symbol)

Comment: That's no definition.

Comment: @gammatester sorry I misread your question. What I meant is the question was not in x^2=-9 form

Comment: OK, but there must be some definition to choose one of the solutions, e.g.
$x=\sqrt{-9}$ if $x^2=-9$ and $\Im(x) > 0.$

Comment: How could we possibly answer this if you don't even tell us what book you're referring to?

Comment: @HansLundmark  It is "Mathematics for International Student ,Mathematics HL(Core) - Haese and Harris Publications"   The question says:  Write in terms of i  squareroot(-9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your text says that. Perhaps that the author is just saying that $3i$ is a square root of $-9$, without saying that it is the only square root.

More generally, *every* non-zero complex number $w$ has two distinct square roots. If $r$ is one such root, then $-r$ is another square root and, since $r\neq0$, $r\neq-r$. Since the equation $z^2-w=0$ can have no more than two roots, there can be no other root.